# How to publish message to IBM WebsphereMQ TOPIC using rubywmq gem

Tags: ruby, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to use rubywmq gem to publish message to a IBM MQ pub/sub topic. I do not see any direct way of publishing to topic from Ruby code.

Following is the MQ TOPIC, SUB setup MQSC:

```
DEFINE TOPIC(MY_TOPIC) TOPICSTR('COM/APP')
DEFINE QALIAS(MY_TOPIC_Q) TARGET(MY_TOPIC) TARGTYPE(TOPIC)

DEFINE QLOCAL(APP.RAW.INPUT)
DEFINE QLOCAL(APP.VALIDATOR.INPUT)
DEFINE QLOCAL(APP.ENRICHER.INPUT)
DEFINE QLOCAL(APP.XFORM.INPUT)
DEFINE QLOCAL(APP.LOGGER.INPUT)

DEFINE SUB(SUB.APP.RAW.INPUT)       TOPICOBJ(MY_TOPIC) TOPICSTR('MSG/RAW') DEST(APP.RAW.INPUT)
DEFINE SUB(SUB.APP.VALIDATOR.INPUT) TOPICOBJ(MY_TOPIC) TOPICSTR('MSG/XML') DEST(APP.VALIDATOR.INPUT)
DEFINE SUB(SUB.APP.ENRICHER.INPUT)  TOPICOBJ(MY_TOPIC) TOPICSTR('MSG/VLD') DEST(APP.ENRICHER.INPUT)
DEFINE SUB(SUB.APP.XFORM.INPUT)     TOPICOBJ(MY_TOPIC) TOPICSTR('MSG/ENR') DEST(APP.XFORM.INPUT)
DEFINE SUB(SUB.APP.LOGGER.INPUT)    TOPICOBJ(MY_TOPIC) TOPICSTR('#')       DEST(APP.LOGGER.INPUT)
```

I also tried publishing to alias queue for the topic with MQRFH2 header
Ruby Code:

```
WMQ::QueueManager.connect(:connection_name => conn_name, :channel_name => channel_name, :q_mgr_name=> queue_manager) do |qmgr|
  message         = WMQ::Message.new
  message.data    = 'Hello World'
  message.headers = [
      {
        header_type: :rf_header_2,
        xml: ['<route>COM/APP/MSG/RAW</route>']
      }
    ]
  message.descriptor[:format] = WMQ::MQFMT_STRING
  qmgr.put(q_name: 'MY_TOPIC_Q', message: message )
end
```

And then add a SUB with selector like:

```
DEFINE SUB(SUB.APP.RAW.INPUT) TOPICOBJ(MY_TOPIC) TOPICSTR('MSG/RAW') DEST(APP.RAW.INPUT) PSPROP(RFH2) SELECTOR('route = ''COM/APP/MSG/RAW''')
```

Couldn't succeed. Could anyone please point where the problem is or suggest an alternative? Thanks.

Software Version Used:

- IBM WMQ Server & Client v7.5
- Ruby v2.3.0
- rubywmq v2.1.1

Answer (score 3):

Putting a message to an alias over a topic is a method to convert point-to-point apps to pub/sub.  Since the API call is PUT and not PUBLISH, there is no mechanism to add a topic string to the prefix supplied by the topic object.  The messages are published to the topic string as defined in the topic object and no further.  Your `SUB.APP.LOGGER.INPUT` subscription should be seeing the publications, but not the other ones.

There are several other issues in the posted code.  The crafting of an RFH2 header suggests you are relying on docs from perhaps as early as v5.3 or v6.  Unfortunately, there is no mention of which version the MQ server is at or which version client libraries are being used by Ruby.

There is also no mention of what you meant by "Couldn't succeed."  Does that mean you saw zero publications, even on `SUB.APP.LOGGER.INPUT` pub appeared to PUT messages OK?  Or the PUT returned a bad reason code?  Or that you got messages on `SUB.APP.LOGGER.INPUT` but nowhere else?

For debugging purposes, you can use MQ Explorer, the `amqsput` sample, or any of the other supplied tools to drop a message onto the alias queue and look for output.  The difference between that test and your Ruby testing should help diagnose the issue.

Please do come back and update your question with additional details if you'd like a less speculative response.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your response. I have updated my question to show versions used. I was able to verify using MQ Explorer that the topic received message when sent to topic queue alias. However, queues subscribed to the topic did not receive messages. Content based routing using PSPROP and SELECTOR didn't work.

Comment: The issue remains that an alias over a topic will *never* result in a topic string longer than that in the topic object.  Since the only possible topic is `COM/APP` no publication will land in the subscription queue, hence nothing for the selector to act on.  I'd suggest running the publisher without the subscriber app until you get messages in the subscription queues.

Answer (score 2):

The *QALIAS* must point to a *TOPIC* object specific to the *TOPICSTR* you want to *publish* to.  Example:

```
DEFINE TOPIC(MY_TOPIC_MSG_RAW) TOPICSTR('COM/APP/MSG/RAW')
DEFINE QALIAS(MY_TOPIC_Q) TARGET(MY_TOPIC_MSG_RAW) TARGTYPE(TOPIC)
```